# How do I reverse a CSV- Python

Tags: python, pandas, alpha-vantage

I'm trying to create a stock market predicting algorithm and I'm using **alpha vantage** as my api for stock prices. However, they store their data from newest to oldest. Is there any way to change this from oldest to newest?

```
ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(self.symbol, outputsize='full')
data.to_csv(f'./{self.symbol}_daily.csv')
print(data)
```

Edit: The CSV is a Data Frame with the following columns: Index (0-2599), Date, Open, High, Low, Close

Comment: What data structure is your CSV stored in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can quickly reformat your data with:

```py
data = data.iloc[::-1]
```

I would recommend reviewing pandas indexing closely from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).